# Python: Defining a class with only Integers Defined

Tags: python, class

I am  defining a class where only a set of integers is used.

I **cannot** use the following datatypes in defining my class: `set, frozenset and dictionaries`.

i need help defining:

`remove(self,i)`: Integer i is removed from the set. An exception is raised if i is not in self.

`discard(self, i)`: integer i is removed from the set. No exception is raised if i is not in self

Comment: Please show us what code you've written so far.

Comment: This is pretty unspecific.  You'll have better luck if you show us what you've tried and ask more specific questions.  This feels like trying to get people to do your homework for you.

Comment: Its not homework, its an exercise in a book but the book doesnt come with answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using an internal list based on what you've said, you could do it like so:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._list = list()

    # all your other methods here...

    def remove(self, i):
        try:
            self._list.remove(i)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("i is not in the set.")

    def discard(self, i):
        try:
            self._list.remove(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

`remove()` tries to remove the element and catches the list's ValueError so it can throw its own. `discard()` does the same but instead does nothing if a ValueError occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot use the following datatypes in defining my class: set, frozenset and dictionaries.

It looks like you are going to use list.
You can use list's `remove` method and handle exceptions in appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's highly inefficient but complete implementation using [`MutableSet` ABC](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes):

```
import collections


class MySet(collections.MutableSet):

    def __init__(self, iterable=tuple()):
        self._items = []
        for value in iterable:
            self.add(value)

    def discard(self, value):
        try: self._items.remove(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def add(self, value):
        if value not in self:
           self._items.append(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._items)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._items)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self._items
```

From `collections.MutableSet` source:

```
def remove(self, value):
    if value not in self:
       raise KeyError(value)
    self.discard(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I did with duplication, take some ideas from it

```
combList = list1 + list2

combList.sort()
last = combList[-1]
for i in range(len(combList)-2, -1, -1):
        if last == combList[i]:
                del combList[i]
        else:
                last = combList[i]

combList.sort()

for i in range(len(combList)):
        print i+1, combList[i]
```

I totally agreed with LiOliQ, the only way is to do it as a list.